# Python - Flask: Importing a .json file from a specific folder and returning on GET/POST request

Tags: python, json, flask

am getting failures importing the JSON file from the folder, I have tried the convention:

```
from web_scraper import data
```

and also

```
from web_scraper.data import *
```

and both didn't work out.
Also, how do I return the JSON file fetched? Is my method

```
return jsonify(bank_list)
```

the correct one?
Here is the snapshot gotten from my PC[image: Python-Flask]

Comment: I have tried `j = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(
 os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'data.json')
data = json.load(j)
  return jsonify(data)
` resulting in "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'"

Answer (score 4):

Your import is wrong. 
First of all, you cannot import JSON in python. Only python files.

If it would be a python file, you'd have to use `from ..web_scraper import data`, as it's in the parent directory (assuming you didn't modify the pythonpath).

To load JSON, you can use the built-in json module.

```
import json
import os

with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "web_scraper", "data.json")) as file:
    data = json.load(file)
# data is a dictionary that you can use in jsonify just fine
```

This would load the file's content and parse the JSON for later use, e.g. in `jsonify`. It's a normal dictionary

Comment: Thanks Jens, I am getting real close to it. However, it responded with syntax error `with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "web_scraper", "data.json") as file:` the arrow was pointing towards the "as" word. Any clues why?

Comment: My bad, add another closing `)` ;) - I updated the snippet

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, couldn't notice that XD thank you very much.